# 'which' command in R with case insensitive

Tags: r

I am trying to find indexes within a data frame which holds a certain string. But I would like my string to be case insensitive.
Say, I want to search for column number in my data frame called COLUMN73 and I expect it to return 73 because it is the seventy third column. I have,

```
which(names(mydata) == "COLUMN73")
```

Is it possible to make my search string case insensitive so as to get 73 even if I search for say, CoLumN73 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert your names to upper cases

```
which(toupper(names(mydata)) == "COLUMN73")
```

Comment: I modded yr code (in my answer) so I could use the same input (a vector of character strings) as Scriven did.

Answer (score 7):

You can index it with `grepl` by using the `ignore.case` argument

```
x <- c("col7", "COL73", "Col17", "CoL73", "cOl73")
grepl("col73", x, ignore.case=TRUE)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Similarly, `grep` returns the numeric index

```
grep("col73", x, ignore.case=TRUE)
# [1] 2 4 5
```

For data frame column subsets

```
df[grepl("col73", names(df), ignore.case=TRUE)]
```

Comment: or `grepl("(?i)col73", x)`

Answer (score 0):

Completely edited,  with a correction for Will's code.  Thanks to David Arenburg for pointing this out.

```
x <- rep(c("col7", "COL73", "Col17","COLUMN73", "CoL73", "cOl73"),1e4)
scriven<- function(x) grepl("COLUMN73", x, ignore.case=TRUE)
will<-function(x) which(toupper((x)) == "COLUMN73")
microbenchmark(scriven(x),will(x))
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 scriven(x) 30.55911 33.04852 34.91243 37.01039 39.59833   100
    will(x) 26.10728 26.47967 27.21592 28.76291 30.46163   100
```

Comment: `x` is an unnamed vector, and thus `which(toupper(names(x)) == "col73")` returns just `NULL`. Also `"col73"` is not upper case so when you do `toupper` it won't match anything... It should be something like `which(toupper(x) == "COL73")` and in that case Richard code should be also modified. You need to make sure `all.equal` returns `TRUE` for both solutions

Comment: @DavidArenburg oops.  Let me re-run with an all-upper argument as the OP requested.

Comment: I think you should change Richards answer to `grep` instead of `grepl` so `all.equal` will return `TRUE`, i.e, `scriven<- function(x) grep("COLUMN73", x, ignore.case=TRUE)`. Sorry for nugging

Comment: @DavidArenburg  doesn't change the process time, but good point about making it easier to verify they give the same answer (as opposed to `which(scriven(x))`  :-)